# Creating complicated line plots in R

Tags: r, plot, bioinformatics

I am trying to make a line plot in R for my CNV data. My .csv file is formatted as follows:

```
    Chromosome     Start       End Call
1         chr1     14620   1577873    2
2         chr1   1595921   1641083    1
3         chr1   1823218   3542170    1
4         chr1   3542242   6695502    1
```

My goal is to have `Call` on the y-axis and `Start` and `End` on the x-axis. I would like this to be a line plot (which creates a line between `Start` and `End` of one CNV as well as the other CNVs).

I know how to make a basic plot (x, y) but I cannot figure out how to make a plot that puts the start and end as different points and then just connects them with a line.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately the formatting was incorrect in my question. The .csv file is formatted into 4 columns (chromosome, start, end, call).

Comment: See `?segments`: Perhaps, something like `plot(NULL, xlim = range(DF[c("Start", "End")]), ylim = range(DF$Call)); segments(DF$Start, DF$Call, DF$End, DF$Call)`?

Comment: @alexis_laz How to create a single plot for all the chromosome and do similar plotting in ggplot2

Comment: @user5249203 : I'm not familiar with ggplot2 to be honest, but I'm sure someone on SO will provide useful feedback if you post a question

Answer (score 2):

As Alexis commented, it is possible to plot your CNV data with [segments](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/segments.html). You could use the following script as a starting point:

**cnv_plot.R**

```
file="cnv_call.txt"
dataTable <-read.table(file, header=TRUE);
ratio<-data.frame(dataTable)
ploidy <- 2 # amplification > 2, deletion < 2 

##
png(filename = paste(file,".png",sep = ""), width = 1080, height = 1080,
units = "px", pointsize = 20, bg = "white", res = NA)
plot(1:10)
op <- par(mfrow = c(5,5))
##

chrom = unique(ratio$Chromosome)
for (i in (chrom)) {
    region <- which(ratio$Chromosome==i)

   #png(filename = paste(file,".",i,".png",sep = ""), width = 640, height = 480,
   #units = "px", pointsize = 20, bg = "white", res = NA)

   if (length(region)>0) {
    plot(ratio$Start[region],ratio$Call[region],xlim = c(0,max(ratio$End[region])),ylim = c(0,max(ratio$Call)),xlab = paste ("position, ",i),ylab = "CNV",pch = ".",col = "black")
    region <- which(ratio$Chromosome==i  & ratio$Call>ploidy )
    segments(ratio$Start[region],ratio$Call[region],ratio$End[region],ratio$Call[region],col = "red",lwd=2)
    region <- which(ratio$Chromosome==i  & ratio$Call<ploidy )
    segments(ratio$Start[region],ratio$Call[region],ratio$End[region],ratio$Call[region],col = "blue",lwd=2)
    region <- which(ratio$Chromosome==i  & ratio$Call==ploidy)
    segments(ratio$Start[region],ratio$Call[region],ratio$End[region],ratio$Call[region],col = "darkgreen",lwd=2)
   }
   #dev.off()
}
##
dev.off()
##
```

[image]